# Why is my document icon visible in properties but not on the Desktop?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have made a cocoa application, documents are saved normally, when I double click on one it automatically opens my app. I just need to figure out how to set file icons.

I have created a .icns icon for files. Here is what I get

[image: screenshot]

As you see the document is "blank" on the desktop but somehow Finder knows about its icon.

Here is my `Info.plist`

```
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
      <string>FileIcon.icns</string>
      <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
      <string>My Type</string>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
      <string>Owner</string>
      <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
      <array>
        <string>xxx</string>
      </array>
      <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
      <string>Document</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

I have tried :

- code above
- code above with not .icns
- Adding New OSX Icon to Images.xcasset with the files I used to create my .icns

All had the same result. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the .icns is not needed, I tested again with the last solution (Adding New OSX Icon to Images.xcassets) and it worked.

Also I don't know if it had an impact or not but I ran :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain user
```

which was posted on SO for someone with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your icon doesn't contain **transparency/alpha value** (if the icon is .png or .tiff). In that case remove the transparency or save as .jpeg.

Comment: and how do you make icons with transparency then ? (e.g the google chrome circle)

Comment: i had the same problem and removing the transparency to the icon, the bug was fix...  I think it's a new Apple HIG ...